# Is there a way to check if my connection to an SSL site is secure in my AIR app?

Tags: flash, ssl, air

I have an AIR app that makes calls to a service on my website. In those calls I use "https". Everything appears to be working correctly and data is returned. I'm using a URLLoader and URLRequest and the data format is loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT.

However, when I visit the website in the browser with "https" the padlock says in the URL says there are some elements that are unsecure or encryption is not strong. I looked at the page elements and there are 3 images I've uploaded to my blog that are still using "http". I'm guessing that's the reason for it. That led me to this question.

Is there a way to tell if my connection in my AIR app is fully secure? In my case I'm calling a service that is returning text value and not loading a webpage but I may be loading a webpage in the future.

Comment: Just a hunch but you might be able to use Fiddler or Charles (mac) to take a look at the server response to see if the data is accessible or encrypted.